# update nessus scan targets using python

Tags: python, nessus

I am trying to update the `nessus` scan targets using python script as the ips of the target servers are not fixed.

The documentation of `python-nessus-client` 0.1.1, does not say anything about updating an existing scan.

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: https://discussions.tenable.com/docs/DOC-1155. The python script shows  how to update the scan in nessus.